# Calling a method from one class in another class

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have this class:

#### boer.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class boer
{
private:

    std::function<void(int id_)> someFun;

public:
    boer();
    ~boer();

    void setSomeFun(std::function<void(int id_)> someFun_);

    void getSomeFun();
};
```

#### boer.cpp

```
#include "boer.h"

boer::boer() { }

boer::~boer() { }

void boer::setSomeFun(std::function<void(int id_)> someFun_)
{
    someFun = someFun_;
}

void boer::getSomeFun()
{
    someFun(12345);
}
```

And this class:

#### aircraft.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include "boer.h"

class aircraft
{
private:

    boer Boer;

public:
    aircraft();
    ~aircraft();

    void source_forSomeFun(int id_);
};
```

#### aircraft.cpp

```
#include "aircraft.h"

aircraft::aircraft() { }

aircraft::~aircraft() { }

void aircraft::source_forSomeFun(int lol_)
{
    std::cout << "AMAZING!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

And I need to connect `void source_forSomeFun(int id_);` in `aicraft` with `std::function<void(int id_)> someFun;` in `boer`. How can I do this? Maybe there is another way, but i think this method is the most preferable.

```
int main()
{
    aircraft Aircraft;
    boer Boer;

    Boer.setSomeFun(???); // here

    Boer.getSomeFun();

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&aircraft::source_forSomeFun`

Comment: No suitable constructor for conversion from "void (aircraft::*)(int id_)" in "std::function<void (int id_)>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boer.setSomeFun([&](int v){aircraft.source_forSomeFun(v);});
```

Use a lambda.

Comment: Some fix:
`Boer.setSomeFun([&](int v) {Aircraft.source_forSomeFun(v);});`
and this work. Thank you!